# customizing kanboard taskmanager

Tags: php, email, customization

Kanboard emails are sent from `my email via banbo.`
and in email body at the end `kanboard` is writen
how to remove these 2 things
which framework is it using that I can get write path to study it

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: google for kanboard taskmanager

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue
1- to change email sender edit `app/core/EmailClient.php` search for `via kanboard`

2- to change footer of email edit `/app/Template/notification/footer.php`

but still don't know which framework they have used, that I can study that 1

Comment: If you got the code just take a look at it. If there's no sign of a specific framework they might just not be using any.

Comment: looks like they have used custom oop, there are only controllers while no model and view folders